# Does System.Net.WebRequest check that SSL certificate is not revoked?

Tags: .net, security, ssl-certificate

I'm connecting to a remote webservice over https using the WebRequest class in .NET 4.0.
I'd like to ensure that the certificate: has not expired, is for the correct domain and hasn't been revoked.

I believe that the WebRequest class already takes care of the expiry and CommonName but I'm unsure if it checks a revocation list, and if it doesn't the best way to achieve this functionality?

Thanks